nginx, php-fpm, max_children, start_servers - too many fpm instances
I'm having trouble figuring out why so many fpm instances are being launched. Here are my ini settings
pm.max_children=1
pm.start_servers=1
pm.min_spare_servers=1
pm.max_spare_servers=2
pm.max_requests=500
pm.process_idle_timeout=10s

enter image description here
Can someone explain this? Clearly doesn't add up.
My best guess is that Nginx is launching dedicated instances independent from the pool. If this is the case, how would I go about limiting the amount of instances Nginx launches?
Thanks in advance!!
So far I've just been playing with the php.ini settings but haven't really dug into the role nginx plays in all this.
Any point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Hi, using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  What if you external resource changes, or stops working? Thank you

Got it. If you're working with CloudPanel, there's an ini file that rewrites the global, admin panel and seems like everything else. "/etc/php/[VERSION]/fpm/pool.d/php.ini"

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
